# react-router changing route doesn't update the page in prod (worked in dev)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

After I build and serve my CRA project, the route changes doesn't update the page at all. It does working fine in dev mode tho.

dependencies:

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.12.1",
```

The page does render if I refresh the page tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I found that updating the `react-router-dom` to version `6.21.0` fixed the problem.
here is the git comment link for the reference: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10579#issuecomment-1584119970

```
- "react-router-dom": "^6.12.1",
+ "react-router-dom": "^6.21.0",
```